# How to have a file repository shared between a few app servers on Linux?

Tags: linux

How to implement a file repository shared among different app servers using Linux?

We have multiple app servers which may need to process the same files uploaded by users. One user may upload to server A and another to server B but both servers should be able to access these files all the time.

There could, of course, be many more servers and all should have access to the same repository.

Comment: Typically the easiest is a file share. --

A shared block device with a cluster file-system allowing concurrent read-write operations is the more classical cluster approach. 
-- 
The more cloud-like solution is to move away from a file-system and use an object store instead.

Comment: References/links/examples?